# strange behavior of printf() inside a while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, printf, getchar

Can some one explain me why I see a double input of the printf() function the while loop:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int x = 0;

    while ( x != 'q'){

    printf("\nEnter a letter:");

    x=getchar();
    printf("%c\n", x);
    if( isalpha(x) )
      printf( "You entered a letter of the alphabet\n" );
    if( isdigit(x) )
      printf( "You entered the digit %c\n", x);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the code in Debian Squeeze (gcc version 4.4.5 (Debian 4.4.5-8)) is:

```
Enter a letter:1
1
You entered the digit 1

Enter a letter: // why is the first one appearing ???


Enter a letter:2
2
You entered the digit 2
```

Comment: The "enter" key produces another character. Make your loop print the char values unconditionally and you'll see. Why did you assume that "printf was behaving strange"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one reads the line terminator character you entered when hitting Enter after 1 (the line terminator will remain in the input buffer).

You can verify this by adding an else branch:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int x = 0;
  while ( x != 'q')
  {
    printf("\nEnter a letter:");
    x = getchar();
    printf("%c\n", x);
    if( isalpha(x) )
      printf( "You entered a letter of the alphabet\n" );
    else if( isdigit(x) )
      printf( "You entered the digit %c\n", x);
    else
      printf("Neither letter, nor digit: %02X\n", x);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
Enter a letter:1
1
You entered the digit 1

Enter a letter:

Neither letter, nor digit: 0A

Enter a letter:2
```

The byte `0A` is the line-feed character.

Comment: OK, I understand. So, how is one supposed to read a single char from std ? scanf("%s", x) does not control more than one letter...

Comment: I would use scanf, and analyze the string I got. If it's not a single character (strlen(x) != 1), then I would print an error message, and give the "Enter a letter:" again. This approach also works if you want to read an integer. In this case the safe way is to read a string, and try to convert it to an integer (atoi).

Answer (score 1):

The second time through the loop, `getchar()` is getting the <kbd>Enter</kbd> after the first char you entered.

You could do something like

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {} /* eat the rest of the line */
```

to get rid of everything up to and including the next <kbd>Enter</kbd> after getting a char and before asking for another.

Comment: hmmm... I don't understand you solution. I does eat the "\n" caused by typing Enter, but it then causes the program to exit the loop.

Comment: this works, paraphrasing your suggestion:
    while ( c != 'q'){ 
    
    printf("\nEnter a letter:");

    
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' && c != 'q') {} /* eat the rest of the line */
    
    
    }

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check characters as you enter  a slightly advanced technique would be to change stdin's behavior to raw mode.Then as soon as the user hits a char you get that in your variable.
[Check this for some start](http://www.lafn.org/%7Edave/linux/terminalIO.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use `CTRL + D` to get the functionality of the newline character without its side effect.